# jQuery find a character very next to character "@" with .next() function

Tags: jquery

I am working on a commenting module of a project,

**Scenario:**  When user presses **@** character and type some like **@jasmine** system should get that specific keyword very next to  **@** character
I am implementing this scenario and getting the key word like this ,

```
$('#commen-text').keyup(function (e) {
if (e.which === 50 && e.next()) {
    var key = $(e.next());
    var filters = {};
    filters['keyword'] = key;
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "filter/user",
        data: {filters: filters},
        type: "get",
        success: function (output) {
            return;
            alert(output);
        }
      });

    }
 });
```

But it gives me following error

> Uncaught TypeError: e.next is not a function

Please suggest me what should i do in this regard

Comment: Please add your `HTML` code too...Also, you can't use `e.next()`. `e` doesn't come from `element`, it comes from `event`, in which better case you can use `e.target.next()`

Comment: <div class="w100">
            <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here" id="commen-text"></textarea>
        </div><!--w100-->

Comment: e.target .next() is not working

Comment: @HassanImam i have difficulty finding the value after @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.. I used indexOf to search for '@' sign in input fields..

EDIT: did mod to capture only after `@` sign.. try to replace `keyup` with `setTimeout` for ex: 500ms and then pull ajax

as I see it, you'll have to watch for 'loosefocus' or similar event to know when user goes away from textarea and then build `filters` keyword.. and then trigger ajax,, not earlier, because you will fire it to soon I guess..

```js
$('#commen-text').keyup(function (e) {
    var key = $(this).val();
    if (key.indexOf('@') > -1 ) {
       console.log( key.split('@')[1] );
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w100"> <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here" id="commen-text"></textarea> </div>
```

Comment: it get all the string with spaces but i need to terminate this function done typing

Answer (score 1):

I've made a bit modified version of your code, but I think it does the trick:

```js
$('#commen-text').keyup(function(e) {
  var current_text = $(this).val();
  if (e.which === 13 && current_text.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
    var key = current_text.split('@')[1][0];
    console.log(key);
    var filters = {};
    filters['keyword'] = key;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w100"> <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here" id="commen-text"></textarea> </div>
<!--w100-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit,  e.next is not a function. Here `e` refers to event not an element

```
$('#commen-text').keyup(function (e) {

if (this.value.indexOf("@") != -1 ) {
    var key = this.value.substring(1, this.value.length);
     debugger;
    var filters = {};
    filters['keyword'] = key;
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "filter/user",
        data: {filters: filters},
        type: "get",
        success: function (output) {
            return;
            alert(output);
        }
      });

    }
 });
```

Comment: what if i want to put a condition this code should only work as type something after @

Answer (score 1):

> For more than one **@**

```js
var names={};
$("#names").focusout(function(){
  $(this).val().split(" ").forEach(function(value){
    value.split("@").slice(1).forEach(function(secValue){
        names[secValue]=secValue
    });
  });
  
    console.log(Object.keys(names));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="names"/>
```